# Problems with PreparedStatement - Java

Tags: java

Im trying to use PreparedStatement to my SQLite searches. Statement works fine but Im getting problem with PreparedStatement.

this is my Search method:

```
public void searchSQL(){
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from ?");
            ps.setString(1, "clients");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but Im getting this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: near "?": syntax error     at
>   org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)    at
>   org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:115)    at
>   org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)    at
>   org.sqlite.PrepStmt.(PrepStmt.java:37)  at
>   org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:231)   at
>   org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:224)   at
>   org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:213)

thx

Comment: I assume you are not going to actually `select *` in your real code. If you are mapping that result set to an Object your logic will break the instant someone else makes a change to your source table.

Answer (score 4):

Columns Parameters can be ? not the table name ;
Your method must look like this :

```
public void searchSQL()
{
    try 
    {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("select * from clients");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here if I do it like this, it's working fine, see this function :

```
public void displayContentOfTable()
{
    java.sql.ResultSet rs = null;
    try
    {
        con = this.getConnection();
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstatement = con.prepareStatement("Select * from LoginInfo");
        rs = pstatement.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            String email = rs.getString(1);
            String nickName = rs.getString(2);
            String password = rs.getString(3);
            String loginDate = rs.getString(4);
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Email : " + email);
            System.out.println("NickName : " + nickName);
            System.out.println("Password : " + password);
            System.out.println("Login Date : " + loginDate);
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        }
        rs.close();  // Do remember to always close this, once you done 
                     // using it's values.
    }
    catch(Exception e)  
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Make ResultSet a local variable, instead of instance variable (as done on your side). And close it once you are done with it, by writing `rs.close()` and `rs = null`.

Comment: @Downvoter : What went wrong ? Please care to interpret, your wisdom.

Comment: @user1232535 : Your Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Answer (score 3):

Passing table names in a prepared statement is not possible.

The method `setString` is when you want to pass a variable in a where clause, for example:

```
select * from clients where name = ?
```

Comment: thx guys,,, Im not getting that error now. 
But, I cant get results from ResultSet using PreparedStatement now :(

     int xRows = 0;  
     while(con_cli.rs.next()) {  
   int cod = con_cli.rs.getInt(1);
   String name = con_cli.rs.getString(2);
   String pet = con_cli.rs.getString(3);
            System.out.println("Cod: " + cod + " - Name: " + name + " - Pet: " + pet);
   xRows ++;  
        } 
    System.out.println(xRows + ": found."); 

thx for replies

Answer (score 1):

thx for replies guys,,,
now its working fine.
I noticed sql query cant hold ? to columns too.
So, this sql query to PreparedStatement is working:

```
String sql = "select * from clients where name like ?";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "a%");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

but, if I try to use column as setString, it doesnt work:

```
String sql = "select * from clientes where ? like ?";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "name");
ps.setString(2, "a%"):
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Am I correct? or how can I bypass this? 
thx again

Comment: Too True, by columns I mean the parameters for columns, my bad I never checked it again, your first code is the write way, to pass parameters for columns.

Comment: thx for replies Bali. So, PreparedStatment wont do the job I was needing then :´(